# BDD Visualization with IPython and GraphViz

Tags: python, binary-decision-diagram, pyeda

I'm Trying to work with PyEDA, i need to visualize Binary Decision Diagram,
i'm reading this document but i can't understand it!

here it says:
If you have GraphViz installed on your machine, and the dot executable is available on your shell’s path, you can use the gvmagic IPython extension to visualize BDDs.

first of all, how can i make the dot executable available on my shell's path?

then, in the document we have this part:

```
In [1]: %install_ext https://raw.github.com/cjdrake/ipython-magic/master/gvmagic.py

In [2]: %load_ext gvmagic
```

is this the DOT environment?

sorry if the questions are so simple and stupid!
i'm not so professional in using Linux.

Comment: Did you install GraphViz?

Comment: Yes i installed Graphviz.

Comment: Good. If you just type dot in the shell, does it work? If it doesn't, you need to add the path where the dot executable is to your PATH. What operating system are you using?

Comment: no it doesn't work when i type dot,
i'm using ubuntu
by the way, how can i add the path where the dot executable is to my path?

Comment: This is really not for stackoverflow as it is not a code question. 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path

Comment: thanks for the link.
sorry by the way.